# Flex3: Is it Possible to Embed a Flex App (which uses a mySQL db) in a WordPress Page?

Tags: apache-flex, wordpress

Is there a way to embed a Flex 3 app in a WordPress page? For example, say I've got a Flex 3 panel with a dataGrid. And I use a ComboBox to control which data is shown in the dataGrid. The data is pulled from a mySQL database.

Is it possible to embed it in a WordPress Page or is this a dumb idea? In the worst case I could always make a completely separate Flex app and link to it from WordPress. But, there are cases where it would be useful to embed it directly.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I know that Flash swfs can be embedded, but I'm not sure about Flex. Does anyone know of a plugin that would work? Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what YouTube does to embed videos.  You can do the same thing.

Here is a snippet I recently used in the [Flextras Blog](https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/3/11/The-Difference-Between-AutoComplete-and-LookAhead) to embed a sWF as part of my post.  That blog is built using BlogCFC, but HTML is HTML and it shouldn't matter if you do this in WordPress or any other blogging software:

```
<embed src="URLToYourSWF.swf" bgcolor="#869ca7" name="Sample" play="true" loop="false" quality="high" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" align="middle" height="150" width="400">
```

Comment: Hi, www.Flextras.com, Thanks so much for the message. I've seen some examples of embedding Flash movies in WordPress Pages, but I haven't found one using Flex.

Comment: @laxmidi Flex is just a framework for Flash.  You can embed a flash movie create with Flex just like you can any other Flash based SWF.

Comment: Hi www.Flextras.com, Thank you for the message. What do I do with the other files that Flex creates, such as AC_OETags.js, assets, history, playerProductInstall.swf etc.?

Comment: Hi, I also saw this plugin (http://orangesplotch.com/blog/swfobj/) for putting Flash content in a WordPress page, but, I'm not sure how to use it with Flex. If anyone has any idea, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: @laxmidi you don't have to do anything w/ those files if you don't want to.  The embed code I posted is all you need.  The other files and JavaScript code offers other functionality, but I never use just for a blog post.  Beyond that, I think I already answered your question about Flex vs Flash: "You can embed a flash movie create with Flex just like you can any other Flash based SWF"

Comment: Hi www.Flextras.com, Thanks you for the help. You're right. I don't need the ancillary files. I got (orangesplotch.com's swfobj plugin to work. Thanks.